# Spring'16 issues with lookup-fields on <force:recordEdit> in standalone LightningApps and LightningOut

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup, lightning-apps, lightning-out

I'm trying to use `<force:recordEdit>` on a Visualforce page via Lightning Out. But there seems to be some rendering issues. Using a standalone Lightning App it looks like this:

[image]

Using LightningOut there are a couple of spinners visible forever.

[image]

The spinners seam to correspond to the lookup fields. Lookups have missing lookup-buttons in the standalone lightning apps, too. I think this is a bug and might be related to [Lightning Components: Using <force:inputField /> on a Lookup only works partly](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96990/lightning-components-using-forceinputfield-on-a-lookup-only-works-partly)

Looking at the markup, I was able to make some hidden elements visible. Maybe they are even partly functional. Visibility and layout is messed-up at least. See here:

[image]

Will this be fixed in either Spring'16 or Summer'16?

Here is the code:

**Component**

```
<aura:component >
    <h2>record display component inside</h2>    
    <force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="001g000000mGaZQ"/>
    <ui:button class="elfSave" label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    save : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("edit").get("e.recordSave").fire();
    },
})
```

**outApp**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:elfLCX_recordEdit"/>   
</aura:application>
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="elfLCX_recordEditWrapper"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">          
        $Lightning.use("c:elfLCX_out", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:elfLCX_recordEdit"
                ,{ label : "Record Edit"}
                ,"elfLCX_recordEditWrapper"
                ,function(cmp) {
                   // do some stuff
                }
            );
        });   
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console of your web browser?

Comment: I wish I would! Lightning is doing a great job in try-catching most errors, hiding them effectively and sometimes showing them (if you are lucky) in custom popups... It's really rare that you get something in the console, which is very sad, because debugging suffers a lot. So the answer is: no, there is no error in the console.

Comment: I believe this is purely a CSS collision issue and would not result in any javascript exceptions. This is also the first report we've had of this so far so no planned fix has even been discussed yet. Please open a case so it can go through the normal support process. I am checking out what I think is the main issue (lack of resetCss.css being auto injected like it is for a standalone .app - can't be auto injected because we know it breaks some things in Visualforce).

Comment: FYI I'm not ale to repro this using force:recordEdit directly (not wrapped in a custom LC) on WInter'16. Digging more.

Comment: Hi Dough, think it's not 100% CSS. I found there is at least on div (lookup__menu uiAbstractList uiAutocompleteList uiInput uiInput--default uiInput--lookup) which seems to be sized with an elements-style (at width: 139px). If I open such a case, support will close it again, I have no premier support.

Comment: @DougChasman the issue happens on a Spring'16 sandbox. I opened a case with the number 13096260. I'm pretty sure, without intervention it will be rejected quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to repro this on Winter'16 with you exact sample in my DE org. Lookups etc all look and function correctly. Even the custom save button works properly. I'm switching to a Spring'16 org now to see if it is release specific.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Doug, I can confirm now, it happens only on the Spring'16 sandbox and not on a Winter'16 DE - so it looks release specific to me.

Comment: Yes, I am able to repro now in a Spring'16 DE org too and I am digging in.

Comment: That's very cool. I'm sure I could hack it somehow, but it's way better handled on your end. Btw. my idea is to use this baby, wrap it into a VF compo to solve this long awaited feature request here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrQtAAK - I'm pretty sure it will work ;-)

Comment: Hi Doug, as you requested, I've opened a case 13096260, which is now closed. If you need the case for the process, please reopen it.

Comment: @UweHeim Did you get it working ? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @thoriyas after they closed my case 13096260, I gave up and haven't tried again yet.